# Qt DBus property convert to map

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qvariant, qtdbus

I need to get a DBus interface's property, so I did `interface.property(name)`. That returns a QVariant, but the map that a QVariant can return is only `QMap<QString, QVariant>`, whereas I need `QMap<QString, QDBusVariant>`. What should I do?

Comment: may be just `qvariant_cast<QDBusVariant>(map.value(key))` for each value of `QMap<QString,QVariant>` when accessing it?

Comment: It inherits from it, so I am pretty sure the cast will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this method as there is no `QVariant::toQDBusVariant()` method, inherently and rightfully:

> [T QVariant::​value() const](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#value)
>
> Returns the stored value converted to the template type T. Call canConvert() to find out whether a type can be converted. If the value cannot be converted, a default-constructed value will be returned.
>
> If the type T is supported by QVariant, this function behaves exactly as toString(), toInt() etc.

Depending on your use case, then you either rebuild the map in one go, or you convert it to your preferred type on the go. Either way, you would use this mechanism as shown by the above example:

```
QVariant myVariant;
...
QDBusVariant dbusVariant;
if (myVariant.canConvert<QDBusVariant>())
    dbusVariant = myVariant.value<QDBusVariant>();
```

You can also go as the [QDBusVariant](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdbusvariant.html#details) example shows:

```
// retrieve the D-Bus variant
QDBusVariant dbusVariant = qvariant_cast<QDBusVariant>(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the `QMap` then

```
QMap<QString,QVariant> variantMap(initializeVariantMapFunction());
QMap<QString,QDBusVariant> dbusVariantMap;
QMap<QString,QVariant>::const_iterator it;

for (it = variantMap.constBegin() ; it != variantMap.constEnd() ; ++it)
    dbusVariantMap.insert(it.key(), qvariant_cast<QDBusVariant>(it.value()));
```

But you could of course, leave `variantMap` as is, and when accessing the value do

```
QDBusVariant someDBusVariant = qvariant_cast<QDBusVariant>(variantMap.value(key));
```

You can use [QVariant::canConvert](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html#canConvert) to check if the conversion if possible.